# import using "from fileName import functionName" run my whole script

Tags: python

I wrote 2 python scripts.

first.py one contains two functions like below:

```
def function1():
    '''do somethong'''
def function2():
    '''do something'''

print("Outside of the functions in first.py")
```

I have imported above two functions from first.py to second.py like below:

```
from first import function1,function2

def function3():
    '''do something with func1 & func2'''

print("Outside of the function in second.py")
```

when i run second.py, it runs whole first.py script even though i have imported  funcion1 & function2 alone.

I am getting output like below:

```
Outside of the functions in first.py
Outside of the function in second.py
```

why it should print the print statement from first.py which is outside of those two functions? How to avoid it, please help.

Comment: Importing a script basically runs the whole thing. You have to take out everything that's not in a function. If you want to run the script on its own as well, put the code you want to run in a properly defined main function (i.e. `if __name__== "__main__":`).

Comment: Read about the `__name__ == '__main__'` guard.

Comment: Running the entirety of first.py is precisely how `function1` and `function2` come into existence.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `import` in python even if you use `from ... import ...` it runs the entire module, the only difference in the 2 ways of imports is the names which get imported.

in order to ensure that module code which is unnecessary when being imported you wrap it in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

`__name__` is set by python and it is set to the module name except when executed directly, then it is set to `__main__`.